# Add initial migration entity framework 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

When I am trying to create an initial migration I am having an error

[image: comnand prompt]

I added the commands and dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {

    "jQuery": "2.1.4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },
```

Any Ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to workaround the issue with this command line

```
dnvm use 1.0.0-rc1-update1
dnx ef migrations add Initial
```